# Generate Sunrise and Sunset Times from Latitude Longitude on today's date

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude

Everyone. I'm doing a project that makes only use of JavaScript (client-side, not server-side) and I want to use the script from NOAA that I found in the other thread (I can't list more than one link as a new user, though) and I found this:

http://www.srrb.noaa.gov/highlights/sunrise/sunrise.html

What I am trying to do is that when a user enters the latitude and longitude and clicks "Submit, " it will get the today's sunrise/sunset data and store them in two variables (sunrise and sunset, as an example).

I really wish, however, that they could have put all teh scripts (except the scripts that embeds in combo boxes) in a separate JavaScript file so that I can provide the source of JavaScript code from NOAA's website into my project that I've been working on.

```
                <div id="locationSetupDiv">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Location</legend>
                        <p>
                        <a href="javascript:var load = window.open('http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/')">
                            Get your longitude and latitude from here.</a>
                        </p>
                        <table class="inputData">
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 75px;">
                                    <label id="labelLongitude" for="inputModuleIDNumber">
                                        Longitude:</label></th>
                                <td><input id="inputLongitude" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label id="labelLatitude" for="inputModuleName">
                                    Latitude:</label></th>
                                <td><input id="inputLatitude" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <input type="button" value="Submit Changes" 
                               style="float: right; margin-top: 1em;" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
```

The above code is in HTML. Now, here's my JavaScript code:

```
function PopulateFromXML()
{
    listModules = document.getElementById(
        "listModules").getElementsByTagName("tbody");

    // Gather the text fields for location data.
    inputLongitude = document.getElementById("inputLongitude")
    inputLatitude = document.getElementById("inputLatitude")

    // Firefox's DOM Parser treats whitespaces as text nodes, including
    // line breaks.
    removeWhitespace(xmlDoc.documentElement);

    // Send the document's root element to the XML Object variable.
        xmlObj = xmlDoc.documentElement;

    // Perform the checks and populate the tables
    // and any other elements that are needed.
    if (xmlObj.tagName == "HomeAutomationInterface")
    {
        // Check to be sure the first node is the "Setup" node. It contains the
        // location node.
        if ((xmlObj.childNodes[0].tagName == "Setup") &&
            (xmlObj.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].tagName == "Location"))
        {
            // Copy the data from one of the attributes to the respective text boxes.
            inputLongitude.value = xmlObj.childNodes[0]
                .childNodes[0].getAttribute("longitude");
            inputLatitude.value = xmlObj.childNodes[0]
                .childNodes[0].getAttribute("latitude");
        }
        // The second node within the root element is Modules node.
        // This will be implemented.
        if (xmlObj.childNodes[1].tagName == "Modules")
        {
            ListModulesInTabularData();
       }
        // The third node within the root element is Scenes node.
        // You need modules in order for scenes to work.
        // This will be implemented.
        if (xmlObj.childNodes[2].tagName == "Scenes")
        {
            ListScenesInTabularData();
        }
        // The last element is the Timers node.
        // This will either activate the scene or turn on, off,
        // dim, brighten, or set the light level of the module if
        // it is the light module or turn on or off the appliance
        // module. This will be implemented.
        if (xmlObj.childNodes[3].tagName == "Timers")
        {
            ListTimersInTabularData();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the two text boxes inside a fieldset gets written when populated from the XML file. Although I'm doing a project as a proof-of-concept, I can't find a way to save all the data to an XML file, so my teacher told me not to worry about that. But since I've written a code to dynamically populate all the XML data in a tabular format, I've been looking for a particular JavaScript code in the Internet or maybe a JavaScript file that I can link to from my project, but with the JavaScript code that I've borrowed from NOAA for my personal project, does anyone know how do I get the sunrise/sunset times according to the latitude, longitude, and today's date?

**Update**

It looks like I found something in the Internet (I did a Google search for: sunrise sunset web service):

http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm

I did a search using keywords "sunrise sunset JavaScript" (without quotes) and it took me a while to search but then with "JavaScript" replaced with "web service, " I am able to find a website I'm looking for, but then I really don't think this will work with XMLHttpRequest when it comes to "same origin policy" in IE8/9 that is suppose to prevent cross-site scripting.

Comment: Basically same question, the javascript is factored out for you. It's linked in the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056555/c-sunrise-sun-set-with-lat-long

Answer (score 2):

I've created a javascript calculator for sunrise and sunset and put it on github [here](http://kybernetikos.github.com/SolarPosition/).  It's based on the calculation published by the National Renewable Energy Laboratory.  I've tried to make it reasonably easy to use, but you're welcome to submit improvements.

Comment: Just came across this. Under which license did you publish it? Couldn't find one in your repo.

Comment: Sorry, I'll eventually get round to fixing that.  I intended it to be MIT licensed.