# XML Feed for determining daylight hours

Tags: xml, datetime, feed

Does anyone know of a feed for determining what time it gets light and dark based on post code or longitude latitude coordinates. We need it for use in a booking system to avoid bookings after dark.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 1):

Odd booking system. Anyway, the [BBC weather feed](http://news.bbc.co.uk/weather/hi/about/newsid_7788000/7788189.stm) gives you sunset and sunrise times. Its in RSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use EarthTools [Sunrise and Sunset Times](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#sun) webservice to get sunrise/sunset times and calculate daylight with them (XML format):

```
http://www.earthtools.org/sun/latitude/longitude/day/month/timezone/dst
```

> Sunrise and sunset times are
>   calculated using a PHP script using
>   formulae from www.srrb.noaa.gov. There
>   might be errors when using latitudes
>   which are close to the poles.

As @Tomasz wrote another way is to use local computation. For example there is easy to use LuckyCat Labs [Sunrise/Sunset Java Library](http://blog.luckycatlabs.com/2009/01/27/release-sunrisesunset-java-library/) for Java ([RubySunrise Gem](http://blog.luckycatlabs.com/2010/03/15/release-sort-of-rubysunrise-gem/) for Ruby is also available).

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of resources over the Internet:

- [C# Sunrise/Sunset with latitude/longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056555) - SO
- http://www.weatherimages.org/latlonsun.html
- http://www.ga.gov.au/geodesy/astro/sunrise.jsp

You don't need a web-service, this is a matter of moderately complicated program (earth is more or less just a spinning ball) which you can run locally.

Answer (score 0):

A few years old of a question, but php has built-in functions to get this data.

```
$reldate=new DateTime();
$reldate->modify('+'.$dayp.' days');
$today['SUNR']=date_sunrise($reldate->format('U'), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, 39.36, -74.60, 90.583333, -4);
$today['SUNS']=date_sunset ($reldate->format('U'), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, 39.36, -74.60, 90.583333, -4);
```