# Get from what type time is now Day or Night

Tags: c#, datetime, location

Is it possible to get what type of time is now --> day or night in the current location. For example now I'm in Bulgaria and time is 2:14 PM or 10:20 AM and this mean now is Day. When is 2.14 AM or 11:20 PM is to be Night. Is have method in .NET who get location on computer and tells in this time is night, or day now.

**EDIT:**
For clarification: Night is start from when is see sunset, and is finish to when is see sunrise

Comment: How do you define _day_ and _night_ exactly?

Comment: Night is start from when is see sunset, to when is see sunrise. And I know for every country is different. For Finland is have day is long around 20 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the BCL that will directly return the sunset/sunrise values. The result depends on the actual location on Earth, not on the `DateTime` culture.

That said, all the mathematical hard stuff has already been written, so you could just translate the existing algorithm in proper C#.

See for example [C# Sunrise/Sunset with latitude/longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056555/c-sharp-sunrise-sunset-with-latitude-longitude)

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit of what you call day and night.

If you define night = between sunset and sunrise on a given location, consider using Nuget package Solar Calculator. That makes calculations as "simple comme bonjour"

Examples from the project web site:

**Sunrise in Chicago**

```
using System;
using Innovative.SolarCalculator;

// ***
// *** Geo coordinates of Oak Street Beach in Chicago, IL
// ***
// *** NOTE: the .Date is not necessary but is included to demonstrate that time input 
// *** does not affect the output. Time will be returned in the current time zone so it 
// *** will need to be adjusted to the time zone where the coordinates are from (there 
// *** are services that can be used to get time zone from a latitude and longitude position).
// ***
TimeZoneInfo cst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
SolarTimes solarTimes = new SolarTimes(DateTime.Now.Date, 41.9032, -87.6224);
DateTime sunrise = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc (solarTimes.Sunrise.ToUniversalTime(), cst);

// ***
// *** Display the sunrise
// ***
Console.WriteLine ("View the sunrise across Lake Michigan from Oak Street Beach in Chicago at {0} on {1}.", sunrise.ToLongTimeString(), sunrise.ToLongDateString());
```

**Sunset in Michigan**

```
// ***
// *** Geo coordinates of Benton Harbor/Benton Heights in Michigan
// ***
TimeZoneInfo est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");              
SolarTimes solarTimes = new SolarTimes(DateTime.Now, 42.1543, -86.4459);
DateTime sunset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(solarTimes.Sunset.ToUniversalTime(), est);

// ***
// *** Display the sunset
// ***
Console.WriteLine("View the sunset across Lake Michigan from Benton Harbor Michigan at {0} on {1}.", sunset.ToLongTimeString(), sunset.ToLongDateString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but you should really checkout [CoordinateSharp](https://github.com/Tronald/CoordinateSharp). It's available via Nuget and really easy to use.

Example

```
//Coordinate Lat, Long, Date
Coordinate c = new Coordinate(25,35,DateTime.Now);
c.CelestialInfo.IsSunUp; //Returns Boolean
```