# Free Sunrise- Sunrise API required

Tags: python, rest, api

I am looking for a free sunrise-sunset API, the one which I found (mentioned below), isn't giving the correct sunset time for Melbourne, Australia (Code Below).

https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=-37.821041&lng=144.963745&date=today

```
import requests
#Get Data from API
r = requests.get('https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=-37.821041&lng=144.963745&date=today')

#Convert Data into JSON format, in this case a Dict
j = r.json()

print(j['results']['sunset'])
```

This gives me 7:31:27 AM

Or any alternative Python Package would also do.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056555/c-sharp-sunrise-sunset-with-latitude-longitude this may help

Comment: How did you conclude that the value is incorrect? What reference did you use?

Comment: @Shiva, The sunset time that the API returns is 07:31:27 AM. That could be sunrise time but it definitely cannot be sunset time. Also, I live in Melbourne and can confirm that the time returned is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The times are in UTC as mentioned on the api page - https://sunrise-sunset.org/api.

[image]

**7:31 AM UTC** translates to **5:31 PM AEST**