# Calculating sunrise / sunset in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to calculate the sunset / sunrise times of several location by the means of VBA. I have a query with a date, location and look up the Lat and Lon in another table.
From several websites I have created code that needed a bit of finetuning, but now comes up with a answer. Unfortunatly the answer is not accurate. I am just wondering where I am going wrong.

Assumption:

```
Date: 08/20/2021
Lat: 52
Lon: 5
Zenith: 96 (civil sunset)
rise: True
Result: Sunrise at 20:04 UTC (which would be 22:30 Local time)
```

[Sunrise sunset algorith](https://edwilliams.org/sunrise_sunset_algorithm.htm)

[Py Calculation](https://github.com/SatAgro/suntime/blob/master/suntime/suntime.py#L134)

My VBA code:

```
Public Const Pi As Double = 3.14159265358979

Function md(Y As Double, X As Double) As Double
' Equivalent of spreadsheet Mod(y,x)
' Returns the remainder on dividing y by x in the range
' 0<=Md <x
md = Y - X * Int(Y / X)
End Function

Function Asn(X)
' Equivalent of spreadsheet Asin(x)
Asn = 2 * Atn(X / (1 + Sqr(1 - X * X)))
End Function

Function Acs(X)
' Equivalent of spreadsheet Acos(x)
If (X >= 0) Then
    Acs = 2 * Atn(Sqr((1 - X) / (1 + X)))
Else
    Acs = Pi - 2 * Atn(Sqr((1 + X) / (1 - X)))
End If
End Function

Function sun(dateinput As Date, lat, lon, zenith, rise As boolean)
'return the UTC of sunrise or sunset in hours
'return -1 if sun never rises, -2 if it never sets
'lat and lon are the lat/lon of the location in degrees
'zenith is the zenith in degrees
'=90.8333333 for official sunset
'=96 for civil twilight
'=102 for nautical twilight
'=108 for astronomical twilight
'rise =True for sunrise, False for sunset

to_rad = Pi / 180

'1. first calculate the day of the year
N1 = Int(275 * Month(dateinput) / 9)
n2 = Int((Month(dateinput) + 9) / 12)
n3 = (1 + Int((Year(dateinput) - 4 * Int(Year(dateinput) / 4) + 2) / 3))
nd = N1 - (n2 * n3) + Day(dateinput) - 30

'2. convert the longitude to hour value and calculate an approximate time
lngHour = lon / 15

If (rise) Then
  t = nd + ((6 - lnghour) / 24)
Else
  t = nd + ((18 - lnghour) / 24)
End If

'3. calculate the Sun's mean anomaly
m = (0.9856 * t) - 3.289

'4. calculate the Sun's true longitude
l = m + (1.916 * sin(to_rad * m)) + (0.020 * sin(to_rad * 2 * m)) + 282.634
l = md(l,360)

'5a. calculate the Sun's right ascension
ra = (1 / to_rad) * Atn(0.91764 * tan(to_rad * l))
ra = md(ra,360)

'5b. right ascension value needs to be in the same quadrant as L
Lquadrant = Int(l/90)*90
RAquadrant = Int(ra/90)*90
ra = ra + (Lquadrant - RAquadrant)

'5c. right ascension value needs to be converted into hours
ra = ra / 15

'6. calculate the Sun's declination
sinDec = 0.39782 * sin(to_rad*l)
cosDec = Cos(Asn(sinDec))

'7a. calculate the Sun's local hour angle
coshr = (cos(to_rad * zenith) - (sinDec * sin(to_rad * lat))) / (cosDec * cos(to_rad * lat))

If (coshr > 1) Then
'The sun never rises on this location (on the specified date)
   sun = -1
ElseIf (coshr < -1) Then
'The sun never sets on this location (on the specified date)
   sun = -2
Else

'7b. finish calculating H and convert into hours
   If (rise) Then
     h = 360 - (1/to_rad)*Acs(coshr)
   Else
    h = (1/to_rad)*Acs(coshr)
   End If
   h = h / 15

'8. calculate local mean time of rising/setting
   t = h + ra - 0.06571 * t - 6.622

'9. adjust back to UTC
   ut = md(t - lnghour, 24)

End If

sun = ut
End Function
```

Comment: Haven't had a close look yet at why the answer isn't accurate.  Must the solution be totally in VBA?  Maybe using COM Interop might be easier if already available solutions.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056555/c-sharp-sunrise-sunset-with-latitude-longitude .  Atm working on COM wrappers of .Net DateTime related classes for VBA so maybe usefull if also dealing with  international DateTime conversions.

Comment: Py code give a different result `2021-08-20 20:56:00-07:00`.

Comment: VBA would be prefered as the data is in a ms access database.

Comment: @Jacco It doesn't matter that the data is Ms-Access.  You can utialize the https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoordinateSharp/ and put a COM Interop wrapper on what you require and create a type library to addin the referencess in MS-Access.   If going down path see VBA-DotNetLib on github.  Examples of wrapping some .Net  classes.  Would require registering the DotNetLib.tlb first and maybe readd the DotNetLib reference for the MS-Access database of examples.  Maybe easier  then "reinventing the wheel".

Comment: If data is in Access, why the Excel tag? I once had to do matrix multiplication. I tested and compared Excel spreadsheet calcs with VBA using Excel functions and also VBA calc without Excel functions. Three methods returned 3 different results.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` and declare each of your variables.

Comment: *Double-precision numbers store an approximation of a real number.*   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/double-data-type

Comment: @Jacco, exactly what VBA does, Python can connect to an MS Access database. See pyodbc or adodbapi packages. VBA is actually an add-on reference library to Office apps and not a built-in component. See first item under Tools \ References.

Comment: What city are you checking sunrise and sunset for?  You can check against https://www.timeanddate.com/  I did quick play around and added the functions to my DotNetLib  thou might remove as not part of the core project. Really should do a separate type library for it.  Getting some nuances with Australian locations and providing the previous day sunset instead of today.  Maybe a bug in their package need further investigating.  I'm guessing you're checking amsterdam sunrise and sunset?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a Web API, this might be a decent approach albeit slower. Here's the API I'm using https://sunrise-sunset.org/api.

You'll need to make sure you have a copy of VBA-JSON project installed.  You can get a copy here --> https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Public Function GetSuntimes(Latitude As Double, Longitude As Double, SearchDate As Date) As String
        
        Dim JSON        As Object
        Dim Endpoint    As String
        
        Endpoint = Replace("https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=@LAT&lng=@LONG&date=@DATE", "@LAT", Latitude)
        Endpoint = Replace(Endpoint, "@LONG", Longitude)
        Endpoint = Replace(Endpoint, "@DATE", Format(SearchDate, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
        
        With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
             .Open "GET", Endpoint, False
             .Send ""
            Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.ResponseText)
        End With
    
        GetSuntimes = JSON("results")("sunrise") & "|" & JSON("results")("sunset")
        
    End Function
    
    Public Sub Example()
        Dim result As Variant
        result = Split(GetSuntimes(36.72016, -4.42034, #8/18/2023#), "|")
        
        'Times are in UTC
        Debug.Print result(0) & " sunrise"
        Debug.Print result(1) & " sunset"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Since I am running Access via WINE, not sure this is going to work. Would love to go a API route

Answer (score 0):

After several stages of debugging and comparing answers side by side I now have a working VBA in access.

The md() function wasn't playing so I replaced it with a If statement:

```
Public Const Pi As Double = 3.14159265358979

Function md(Y As Double, X As Double) As Double
' Equivalent of spreadsheet Mod(y,x)
' Returns the remainder on dividing y by x in the range
' 0<=Md <x
md = Y - X * Int(Y / X)
End Function

Function Asn(X)
' Equivalent of spreadsheet Asin(x)
Asn = 2 * Atn(X / (1 + Sqr(1 - X * X)))
End Function

Function Acs(X)
' Equivalent of spreadsheet Acos(x)
If (X >= 0) Then
    Acs = 2 * Atn(Sqr((1 - X) / (1 + X)))
Else
    Acs = Pi - 2 * Atn(Sqr((1 + X) / (1 - X)))
End If
End Function

Function sun(dateinput As Date, lat, lon, rise As Boolean)
'return the UTC of sunrise or sunset in hours
'return -1 if sun never rises, -2 if it never sets
'lat and lon are the lat/lon of the location in degrees
'zenith is the zenith in degrees
'=90.8333333 for official sunset
'=96 for civil twilight
'=102 for nautical twilight
'=108 for astronomical twilight
'rise =True for sunrise, False for sunset
zenith = 90.8333333333333
to_rad = Pi / 180

'1. first calculate the day of the year
N1 = Int(275 * Month(dateinput) / 9)
n2 = Int((Month(dateinput) + 9) / 12)
n3 = (1 + Int((Year(dateinput) - 4 * Int(Year(dateinput) / 4) + 2) / 3))
nd = N1 - (n2 * n3) + Day(dateinput) - 30

'2. convert the longitude to hour value and calculate an approximate time
lnghour = lon / 15

If (rise) Then
  T = nd + ((6 - lnghour) / 24)
Else
  T = nd + ((18 - lnghour) / 24)
End If

'3. calculate the Sun's mean anomaly
m = (0.9856 * T) - 3.289

'4. calculate the Sun's true longitude
L = m + (1.916 * Sin(to_rad * m)) + (0.02 * Sin(to_rad * 2 * m)) + 282.634
'l = md(l, 360)
If (L < 0) Then
   L = L + 360
ElseIf (L >= 360) Then
   L = L - 360
End If

'5a. calculate the Sun's right ascension
ra = (1 / to_rad) * Atn(0.91764 * Tan(to_rad * L))
'ra = md(ra, 360)
If (ra < 0) Then
   ra = ra + 360
ElseIf (ra >= 360) Then
   ra = ra - 360
End If

'5b. right ascension value needs to be in the same quadrant as L
Lquadrant = (Int(L / 90)) * 90
RAquadrant = (Int(ra / 90)) * 90

ra = ra + (Lquadrant - RAquadrant)

'5c. right ascension value needs to be converted into hours
ra = ra / 15

'6. calculate the Sun's declination
sinDec = 0.39782 * Sin(to_rad * L)
cosDec = Cos(Asn(sinDec))

'7a. calculate the Sun's local hour angle
coshr = (Cos(to_rad * zenith) - (sinDec * Sin(to_rad * lat))) / (cosDec * Cos(to_rad * lat))


If (coshr > 1) Then
'The sun never rises on this location (on the specified date)
   sun = -1
ElseIf (coshr < -1) Then
'The sun never sets on this location (on the specified date)
   sun = -2
Else

'7b. finish calculating H and convert into hours
   If (rise) Then
     h = 360 - (1 / to_rad) * Acs(coshr)
   Else
     h = (1 / to_rad) * Acs(coshr)
   End If
   h = h / 15

'8. calculate local mean time of rising/setting
   T = h + ra - (0.06571 * T) - 6.622

'9. adjust back to UTC
   ut = T - lnghour
   'ut = md(ut, 24)
If (ut < 0) Then
   ut = ut + 24
ElseIf (ut >= 24) Then
   ut = ut - 24
End If
sun = ut

End If

End Function
```